# How i can get from an array with multiple object, same array but with only specific keys and values?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

If i have an arr like the following

```
const myArray = [
    {
        key: 'blah',
        value: 'Blah Blah'
    },
    {
        key: 'foo',
        value: 'Foos'
    }
];
```

how I can get from it the following only using js

```
[
    {
        key: 'blah'
    },
    {
        key: 'foo'
    }
];
```

Comment: do you want to remove the value from each object?

Comment: Try the filter() function in JavaScript.  You'll find several solutions on this site.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: myArray.map(i => ({key: i.key}))

Comment: Following the above link, you can do something like so with destructuring: `const res = myArray.map(({key}) => ({key}))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map the array to achieve this, like shown below:

```js
const myArray = [{
    key: 'blah',
    value: 'Blah Blah'
  },
  {
    key: 'foo',
    value: 'Foos'
  }
];

const result = myArray.map((item) => {
  return {
    key: item.key
  }
})

console.log(result)
```